# Trying to understand an error - wintypes.Structure

Tags: python, spyder

I'd need help trying to figure out this thing.
Yesterday I installed the beta of Spyder 2.3 to work with Anaconda Python 3.3, on my Win7 64-bit laptop.
Opening an internal console window, I noticed an error that triggered every sec,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\status.py", line 80, in update_label
  self.label.setText('%d %%' % self.get_value())
File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\status.py", line 93, in get_value
  return memory_usage()
File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\utils\system.py", line 20, in windows_memory_usage
  class MemoryStatus(wintypes.Structure):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Structure'
```

This appears to come from the fact that [system.py](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/source/browse/spyderlib/utils/system.py?r=0943fd32156ab3795d7d7b4eae6a39c003d2afe7&spec=svn0df476e899cec2eac10b9c59bfe67ddc4ca1dcf1) tries to use "`wintype.Structure`" when `psutil` is not installed, and I can see no such thing as a Structure class (or module) in [wintypes.py](https://github.com/cocoatomo/Python3.2_C_API_Tutorial/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/wintypes.py)... Even `c_uint64` is not in `wintypes`.

I solved the issue the easy way - I just installed `psutil` and was done. But the fact is that several scripts appear to use `wintypes.Structure` (see [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=python%20%22wintypes.Structure%22%20-spyderlib)). And I really don't see it... so what am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Try: from wintypes import Structure

Comment: Even if I set the cwd to be that of `ctypes`, so that I can directly `from wintypes import Structure`, I get: `ImportError: cannot import name Structure`

Comment: `name 'Structure' is not defined` though

Comment: even if you import like this: from ctypes import wintypes? Or from ctypes.wintypes import Structure?

Comment: I can do `from ctypes import wintypes` - but there is no `wintypes.Structure` then. And `ctypes.wintypes import Structure` gives the same `cannot import` error

Comment: OOH but there is a `wintypes.ctypes.Structure`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm editing my answer.

The problem here appears to be that the Python 2.7 version of wintypes.py (from the ctypes 1.1.0 package) starts with
`from ctypes import *`

while wintypes.py from the Python 3.3 ctypes 1.1.0 package uses:
`import ctypes`

So basically `wintypes.Structure`, `.c_uint64`, `.sizeof` and `.byref` are all from `ctypes`. They don't get altered in `wintypes` - at least not up to this 1.1.0 version. So this change to Spyder(2.3.0beta3)'s `status.py` should make it work with no errors both for Python 2.7 and Python 3.3:

```
def windows_memory_usage():
    """Return physical memory usage (float)
    Works on Windows platforms only"""
    from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_uint64, sizeof, byref
    from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD
    class MemoryStatus(Structure):
        _fields_ = [('dwLength', DWORD),
                    ('dwMemoryLoad',DWORD),
                    ('ullTotalPhys', c_uint64),
                    ('ullAvailPhys', c_uint64),
                    ('ullTotalPageFile', c_uint64),
                    ('ullAvailPageFile', c_uint64),
                    ('ullTotalVirtual', c_uint64),
                    ('ullAvailVirtual', c_uint64),
                    ('ullAvailExtendedVirtual', c_uint64),]
    memorystatus = MemoryStatus()
    # MSDN documetation states that dwLength must be set to MemoryStatus
    # size before calling GlobalMemoryStatusEx
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366770(v=vs.85)
    memorystatus.dwLength = sizeof(memorystatus)
    windll.kernel32.GlobalMemoryStatusEx(byref(memorystatus))
    return float(memorystatus.dwMemoryLoad)
```